# Laravel 5.2 Job with delay fires instantly instead of waiting

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-5

I'm creating an application with the Laravel 5.2 framework. In my application there is a job that I want to fire 2 days after the event.

This is the code where an instance of the right job is made and where I set the delay to the amount of seconds that equals 2 days.

```
 $job = (new RemoveNotPayedOrder($order))->delay(172800);

 $this->dispatch($job);
```

Right when the code reaches the dispatch method the job gets fired instantly instead of waiting the seconds specified by me in the delay method.

I generated the Job class with the make:job command provided by php artisan.

I've read the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs and I think my code is correct. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: What queue server are you using?

Comment: I'm developing local with MAMP.

Comment: Please include your config/queue.php file in your question. I'm assuming you don't have an actual queue server installed and running?

Comment: You're correct! I never knew about the queue driver. It was set to 'sync' which clearly does not work. I have set it to database and ran a migration to create a jobs table. It now works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: np, ill post that as the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue ended up being the queue driver (in `config/queue.php`) was set to 'synchronous'.